# How can I figure out why my laptop optical drive no longer reads CDs/DVDs?

Tags: fedora, dvd, media, optical-media

## Summary

My laptop's optical drive stopped reading discs a while ago, but I'm never given an error; I want to figure out what exactly is wrong with my optical drive.

## Background

This is a Toshiba Satellite laptop with Fedora 27. `dmesg` identifies the drive as MATSHITA DVD-RAM UJ8E2.

## Details

I noticed the drive stopped reading some time ago after traveling. It may have taken shock damage then, but I'm not sure since I only read CDs/DVDs occasionally (so I don't have an accurate timeline for when it stopped working).

When a disc is inserted, I hear the optical drive spin and it sounds like some data is read, but my system never acknowledges that a disc is there. Eventually, the drive spins down.

## Linux commands to troubleshoot?

I found some older questions, but they were about verifying the integrity of the actual disc media, not the drive itself. Are there any tools to help me debug / figure out the point of failure on an optical drive?

Comment: First thing which comes to mind is try cleaning the lens. If this is not it the drive might be defective.

Comment: Given how CD drives generally work if the sensor is bad this won't be seen as a read error. It'll just do what you mention. It's the same behavior if no disc was inserted. The sensor checks for a disc nothing reads back and it assumes no disc is present. In this case the sensor is just bad.